# Avoiding string to be considered optional in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I have a function where string value is defined based on value in dictionary. If value in dictionary is not found, I set it to static string. String is constant (`let`):

```
let dict = [ 1: "a", 
             2: "b" ]

func x() {
    let index = someFunctionReturnsInt()
    let str = (nil != dict[index]) ? dict[index] : "N/A"
```

So string cannot possibly be `nil`. However, when I try to use `str`, Swift still considers it an optional. For example:

```
    // still inside the same function
    os_log("Str is %@", str)
```

will return a compiler error:

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'

Thing is, I use this function quite a few times, and adding `str ?? "N/A"` on every occasion makes no sense. Force-unwrap with `str!` seems like an overkill: this string is not critical to the app, so I don't think aborting execution if it's missing makes any sense.

So is force-unwrap the only solution, or is there a better way to define a string as non-optional and "never going to be nil"?

Comment: You already know about the `??` operator. What is wrong with `let str = dict[index] ?? "N/A"`?

Comment: @robmayoff you are right, didn't think it would make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `dict[index]` is still returning an optional so `str` has to be an optional. There are two ways you can fix it

You can use the nil coalescing operator to use `dict[index]` if its not nil otherwise use "N/A"

```
let str = dict[index] ?? "N/A"
```

Another option is to use the dictionary default value subscript

```
let str = dict[index, default: "N/A"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should simply use the nil coalescing operator when defining the `str` itself. Checking if the value is nil, then still assigning the optional value without unwrapping makes no sense.

```
let str = dict[index] ?? "N/A"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use nil coalescing operator - `let str = dict[index] ?? "N/A"`

Instead of `let str = (nil != dict[index]) ? dict[index] : "N/A"`

The reason because str is still optional in your case is because `dict[index]` is optional even if you are checking it to be no nil. So, swift infers the type of str to be String?

You could also force unwrap because you are already checking it to be no nil like -
`let str = (nil != dict[index]) ? dict[index]! : "N/A"`

But force unwrapping should be avoided whenever possible